# AngularJS Bindings between component

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm not very confortable with Bindings in Angular (1.5), each time I tried I had a lot of trouble to resolve my problems so I guess I'm missing something or doing something wrong and I hope you might help me.

So this is `mapping.component.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('mapping', mapping());

  /** @ngInject */
  function mapping() {

    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/containers/mapping/mapping.html',
      controller: mappingController,
      controllerAs: 'mc'
    };

    function mappingController($log, $newDrupal, $stateParams, $http) {

    var mc = this;
    var Drupal = new $newDrupal();

    mc.paragraph = Drupal.getParagraphs(...);
    .
    .
    .
    $http.get(...).success(function (data) {
    }
  } ...
```

`rendition.component.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('rendition', rendition());

  /** @ngInject */
  function rendition() {

    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/rendition/rendition.html',
      controller: renditionController,
      bindings: {
        canvasdata: '<',
        renditions: '<'
      },
      controllerAs: 'rd'
    };

    function renditionController($log, $newDrupal, $stateParams, $http) {
```

With `mapping.html`

```
<rendition canvasdata="mc.canvasdata" renditions="mc.renditions"></rendition>
```

and

```
rendition.html

<pre> {{ rd.canvas | json }} </pre>
<pre> {{ rd.renditions | json }} </pre>
```

but rd.canvas and rd.renditions are `"undefined"` and I don't understand why.

Comment: In mapping.html you pass to the component mc.canvasdata and mc.renditions. Do you have them defined in mapping.component?

Comment: Yes, below var Drupal = new $newDrupal(); they are defined as mc.canvasdata = new Array();
      mc.renditions = new Array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, in my `index.route.js` I had

```
.state('main.publication.paragraph', {
        url: '/paragraphs/:idParagraph/page/:idPageParagraphs',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/rendition-map.html'
      })
```

but in `rendition-map.html`, I was calling `<rendition>` instead of `<mapping>` which is calling himself `<rendition>`, so variables were undefined and I had to go through promise to make it works.

```
rendition-map.html
<mapping></mapping>

mapping.html
<rendition renditions="mc.renditionsPromise"></rendition>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `rendition` is not a child of `mapping` so `mc.canvasdata` is undefined.

Set the `mapping` template like this:

```
<mapping>
  <rendition canvas="mc.canvasdata"...></rendition>
</mapping>
```

Comment: last time someone talked about "child" I had to use <ui-view>, could it be a reason ? I'll check this side.

Comment: structuring you components in a hierarchy has nothing to do with ui-view...